# Ошибка: "Не определен базовый класс"

Tags: c++, наследование

Не могу понять в чем ошибка при наследовании, компилятор пишет, что не определен базовый класс, хотя все заголовки и определение класса я сделал. Вот полный текст ошибки: `C2504   Node: не определен базовый класс`.

list.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "node.h"

#include <iostream>

class Node;

class List : public Node {
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const List& list);

private:
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    Node* curr;

    char min;

    size_t size;
public:
    void push(char value);
    void update();

    Node* remove(Node* node = nullptr);

    Node* getCurr() const;
    Node* getTail() const;
    Node* getHead() const;

    Node* operator++();
    Node* operator--();

    List();
    ~List();
};
```

node.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "list.h"

#include <iostream>

class List;

class Node {
    friend List;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const List& list);

private:
    char value;

    Node* next;
    Node* prev;
protected:
    Node* insert(Node* node);
    Node* excluse();

    explicit Node(char value = 0);
    ~Node() = default;
public:
    char getValue() const;
    void setValue(char value);
};
```

Comment: Текст ошибки приведите в вопросе целиком, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Kromster Ошибка C2504 Node: не определен базовый класс

Comment: При компиляции ЧЕГО? просто у вас, заметим, циклическая зависимость (разбитая pragma once), так что компиляция при включении заголовка зависит от того какой и в каком порядке включены. Что именно вы *компилируете*?

Comment: @Harry вообще я компилю `main`, а там подключается только `list.h`

Comment: Не наоборот? Смотрите - как только включается первый файл, отрабатывает once, и при включении второго фaйла первый не включается. Если первый node.h - то он тянет list.h, но в list.h уже node.h не грузится (once!) и в `class List: public Node` класс `Node` присутствует только как forward declaration - и получается ваша ошибка... Так, как вы делаете - это прямая дорога к труднообнаруживаемым ошибкам, вот такие зависимости между файлами. Какой вообще глубокий смысл разносить по разным файлам **настолько тесно связанные** классы??

Comment: кнопка "править" под вопросом. Используйте ее для внесения уточнений в вопрос.

Comment: @Harry ну в Бауманке и не такое бывает -_-, да спасибо все вы помогли

Comment: @splkmaxdk, скорее всего Вам необходимо перенести``#include "list.h"`` из ``node.h`` в ``node.cpp``, это должно решить проблему

Comment: зачем вам два раза `#include <iostream>` если вы собираетесь наследовать один класс в другой?

Answer (score 1):

Как сказано в комментариях, у вас циклическая зависимость в #include. Проблема в том, что базовый класс у вас дружествен к наследнику. Это явная ошибка инкапсуляции. Все поля Node, которые могут понадобиться List, должны быть public или protected. node.h не должен инклюдить list.h. Вообще про него знать ничего не должен.